# XNA PC vs Monogame Online Multiplayer

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, networking, monogame

I've got a mostly working PC game in XNA 4, and am looking to make it networked.  From the documentation it seems that I can use XNA Networking through GFWL to do LAN sessions, but not online sessions (without each account paying microsoft a bucket of cash...).  I started poking around and found MonoGame, but their documentation is kinda scattered.  They have a peer to peer sample, but I'd like to know if this translates to the ability to find online sessions before I get started porting my game.

Comment: Could you clarify your actual question? You provide a lot of background detail, but you may want to revise your question if you wish to get better answers.

Comment: You can use sockets in both, so it doesnt matter. Take a look at lidgren library. https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network/

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to create an online game using the library provided by monogame.

Comment: This is basically a "which technology to use" question. Hence voting to close.

Comment: Also, there's no question in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing networking through XNA or Monogame.

Use C# / .net's built in System.Net code.

Specifically, sockets... just google "C# .net sockets client-server example" or similar things, and start learning how sockets work. Make an online chat room or something to practice... when you got it down, you can directly move your code over to your XNA or Mono project.